# Detect multiple keypresses on Firefox (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

So I'm trying to be able to trigger a script using a combinations of keypresses.

```
var down = {
};

    $(document).chardown(function (e) {
      down[e.charCode] = true;
    }).charup(function (e) {
      if (down[68] && down[69] && down[86]) {
        var nextButton = document.getElementsByClassName('button-next') [0];
        nextButton.click();
      }
      down[e.keyCode] = false;
    });
```

This is the code I've got so far. So the intention is (afaik) to trigger the

```
 var nextButton = document.getElementsByClassName('button-next') [0];
        nextButton.click();
```

When I press e+d+v. But it isn't working. And if I only use the above part it keeps changing episode (Obvioulsy).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation related to chardown and charup in jquery or greasemonkey.I think you were trying to use keydown and keup. You should replace charCode with keyCode.

```
var down = {};
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  down[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keyup(function (e) {
  if (down[68] && down[69] && down[86]) {
    alert("Hello");
  }
  down[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Comment: I guess I'll try that. I've just been told that for firefox you need to do charCode instead of keyCode.

Edit: Doesn't seem to be working either